# How to fix parts of a <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Let's say there is a textarea, but I want to fixed "I like" don't let people edit they only can ready "I like" but they can change the basketball.

```html
<textarea>I Like basketball.</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an alternative method. `<textarea>` by itself doesn't have capabilities to hold non-editable text.

For the same idea based on your example. Something as simple as the following would have the same effect after CSS scripting:

```
<p><label>I like</label><input type="text" placeholder = "basketball" id="input"></p>
```

Comment: <h4><label>trav &nbsp;</label><input style="border:none;" type="text" placeholder = "basketball" id="input"></h4> done!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to implement something like this-> [link](http://www.instructables.com/)

Let's assume you don't want to use "complex codes". If i had to implement this in some way because my employer wanted me to, I'd not use a textarea in the first place. Especially, if you're expecting the user to type in a sport, or 2-3 words.

There are ***two ways*** I would do this.

Either by using **bootstrap input group**.Code is a sample from the bootstrap documentation.Check the link for additional help-> [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Else,define an input field, let the placeholder be "I like basketball" .Then using the method **`onblur`**,  in a function,
return

`var x="I like" + newinput;`

Alternatively, let the I like be in `<p>` tags, and the input field a blank after that with an initial placeholder of basketball.

Comment: yes, exactly that the thing i need. but the page is not responsive.. it's only show on full page can't edit the size.. but i need to figure a way make it for col-sm-12 something.. because our target is on tab, and handset

Comment: I believe you mean you want it to work for the whole screen width?What you can do is, get the device screen width through media queries, and accordingly ensure that the width is x for a tab, and y for a handset. Check the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: i do have this thing in my coding already, but still not very responsive, because inside the col-sm-12, have 3(col-sm-4), inside one of the col-sm-4 have many row, and the label taking col-sm-8 and user text take col-sm-4.. you get my mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost not possible without some complex js codes which is not recommended. As a suggestion the following [link](http://www.felgall.com/htmlt169.htm) suggests a simple way basing on two different text areas,  where you play with the styles to make them seem as one.

Comment: but my company want me to do this... i like to challenge.. i had tried a lot of ways.. now i ask for help==

Comment: @Jaromanda not really understand how to write "complex js codes" in the answer?

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, the time make it urgent.. 1 brain better than more brain? need to launch new web in next monday.. so need find a solution first before it stop us.. consider for output first, else be fired==